# Plotting to a file from a function in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

### Background

Hey everyone!

I'm new to using R, and became interested in using it after having a team member give a tutorial of how useful it can be in an academic setting.

I am trying to write a script to automatically read my data from multiple files and then plot the resultant graphs to multiple files, so that they can be easily added to a manuscript (PowerPoint, latex, etc.)

### Problem

I have found that the following code will allow me to produce a graph

```
p = qplot(factor(step), y, data=x, colour=c))
p = p + theme_bw()
# etc...
```

wrapping this around a `png` call will allow me to output the plot to a PNG:

```
png("test.png")
p = qplot(factor(step), y, data=x, colour=c))
p = p + theme_bw()
# etc...
p
dev.off()
```

I wanted to put the graph creation into a function so that I can create graphs and consequent seperate PNGs.  So I put everything into a function:

```
func <- function()
{
    png("test.png")
    p = qplot(factor(step), y, data=x, colour=c))
    p = p + theme_bw()
    # etc...
    p
    dev.off()
}
```

If I call `func()` A PNG is created, but it is empty.  Is there any specific reason why I can do this without the function but can't when I'm calling it from a function?

Comment: When using the ggplot2 package, it's often easier to use the `ggsave` function rather than `png`, etc.

Comment: I actually just learned about this function today, so I am currently using that.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using `ggplot2` or `lattice` non-interactively (i.e. not from the command-line), you need to explicitly `print()` plots that you've constructed. So just do `print(p)` in the final line of your code, and all should be fine.

This is unintuitive enough that it's one of the most frequent of all [FAQs](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f).

Comment: Works like a charm!  I'm stupid not to have looked in the FAQs.  Thanks!

Comment: Not stupid at all, though it **is** a good reminder isn't it? There's gold in them there FAQs!

Comment: ... and I'd likely take @baptiste's advice, as an only occasional `ggplot2` user myself.

Comment: Finally found this solution for why I wasn't able to use an existing plot as an input to a function and draw on top of it. Need to `print(foo)`, `abline(x)`, `recordPlot()`.