# Can you create an invisible plot in R? How to switch from one plot to another?

Tags: r, plot

Well, the question is as simple as this: can you create an **invisible plot** in `R`? Can you create a plot without displaying it until you decide to do so?

Suppose you have the following code:

```
x <- (0:360) / 180 * pi
y <- sin(x)
z <- cos(x)
plot(x, y)
dev.new()
plot(x, z)
```

The code above will immediately display the second plot and hide the first.

Suppose you want to *create* and *build* the second plot but not *display* it until you actually decide to do so: not before. In the meantime, while you *build* the second plot you want to keep displaying the first plot. Is there a way to do that?

Also, once you have two plots, how do you switch from one to the other, i.e. choose to display one or the other as needed?

Functions `dev.set`, `dev.cur`, `dev.prev` and `dev.next` are useful to make windows active or inactive; however I could not make them hide the second plot while displaying the first and then switch from displaying the first to displaying the second.

Note that I do not want to shut windows, just switch from one to the other as needed. Also, I do not need to create `gif` animations.

Comment: Consider using a plotting library other than base graphics. Base graphics plot directly to the graphics device. Libraries like `lattice` and `ggplot2` allow you to specify/build a plot that will only render when you `print()` it.

Comment: Can you make an example? Will rendering be slower than just plotting?

Comment: @rappr - see here maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993479/plotting-to-a-file-from-a-function-in-r/8993646

Comment: Ok, I have installed ggplot2 and I am creating the two plots: `p = qplot(x, y)` and `q = qplot(x, z)`. When I execute `print(p)` and then `print(q)` the plots are displayed in the same window (perhaps the second covering the first? Or replacing it?). (I need to check if this is what I needed).

Comment: You want them to be on the same plot, is that it? If so, you can use `ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=z))` although the ideal would be creating one dataframe with all the data and use that instead of two `geom_line`s, e.g.: `df <- data.frame(x=rep(x, 2), val = c(y, z));qplot(x=x, y=val, data=df)`

Comment: Why not create two dev.new() then arrange them side by side and switch between them while plotting? You will be able to see both of them at the same time.